# Why is can't the Route class be found?

Tags: php, laravel

I have got this error when i was trying to run default project in PhpStorm:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});   
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in ... Stack trace: #0 {main}   thrown in C:\composer\startLaravel\routes\web.php on line 14

Comment: You need to setup your project correctly, it seems that the autoloader is not working. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation

Comment: In the future, format your post correctly and I would suggest you learn the basics of OOP before you use a framework such as Laravel.

Comment: What do you mean by `trying to run default project in PhpStorm`?  How were you trying to run it?  You wouldn't be able to execute web.php without bootstrapping the framework.

Comment: After all, not only get the autoloader running, but also include it in your file

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've not run "composer install" on the project. If you've done, try composer dump to rebuild the autoload class

Comment: You are answering a question to a an individual who is new to PHP ***and*** Laravel. I would include some explanations as to *why* and *what* that would achieve.